# "Invalid calling object" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a code that works in both chrome and mozzila without any error, and there is this IE 11 that trows this error. This is the code:

```
  var products;

                function search()
                {

                    var tag;
                    var flag = 0;
                    var searchword = document.getElementById("search-bar").value;

                    for(var i=0; i< products.length; i++)
                    {

                        tag = products[i].getElementsByTagName("itemnumber");
                    if( searchword.toUpperCase() == tag[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase() )
                    {

                        // do something
}

                    }
                }



                $(window).load(function() {

                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            myFunction(this);
                        }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("GET", "products.xml", true);
                    xhttp.send();

                    function myFunction(xml) {
                        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

                        products = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");


                    }
                });
```

This code gives me this error:

```
Unable to get property 'toUpperCase' of undefined or null reference
```

for `searchword` ???

and if I were to add this

```
if(products.length === 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

just at the start of the `function search();`

it would give me `Invalid Calling Object` error at `products.length` ??

Why, just why, I don't get it...?

And also, when I try `alert(products.length);` in console, `Invalid Calling object` pops up.

I really don't have any idea why is this happening, since it works fine in both chrome and mozzila. If anyone knows why is this and how to fix it, please answer.

P.S. This code is placed inside head in script tag. Search invokes on button click.

Comment: show us the code where toUpperCase has

Comment: I edited the question, sorry about that

Comment: check in console `tag[0].innerHTML `

Comment: ah, it says that it is undefined

Comment: then use console.log everywhere and see where it is stuck